# Uploading various sized Images to AWS Cloudfront versus post processing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We are using AWS cloudfront to render static contents on our site with origin as S3 BUCKET. Now as next steps, the user can dynamically upload images which we want to push to CDN. But we would require different sizes of it so that we can use it later in in the site. One option is to actually do preprocessing of images before pushing to S3 BUCKET . This ends up creating multiple images based on sizes. Can we do post processing something like http://imageprocessor.org/imageprocessor-web/ does but still use cloudfront. Any feedback would be helpful.

Regards
Raghav

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, it is possible to do post-processing and use CloudFront but you need an intermediate layer between CloudFront and S3.  I designed a system using the following high-level implementation:

- Request arrives at CloudFront, which serves the image from cache if available; otherwise CloudFront sends the request to the origin server.
- The origin server is **not** S3.  The origin server is Varnish, on EC2.
- Varnish sends the request to S3, where all the resized image results are stored.  If S3 returns 200 OK, the image is returned to CloudFront and to the requesting browser and the process is complete.  Since the Varnish machine runs in the same AWS region as the S3 bucket, the performance is essentially indistinguishble between CloudFront >> S3 and CloudFront >> Varnish >> S3.
- Otherwise, Varnish is configured to retry the failed request by sending it to the resizer platform, which also runs in EC2.
- The resizer examines the request to determine what image is being requested, and what size.  In my application, the desired size is in the last few characters of the filename, so xxxxx_300_300_.jpg means 300 x 300.  The resizer fetches the source image... resizes it... stores the result in S3... and returns the new image to Varnish, which returns it to CloudFront and to the requester.  The resizer itself is Imagemagick wrapped in Mojolicious and uses a MySQL database to identify the source URI where the original image can be fetched.

Storing the results in a backing store, like S3, and checking there, first, on each request, is a critical part of this process, because CloudFront does not work like many people seem to assume.  Check your assumptions against the following assertions:

- CloudFront has 50+ edge locations.  Requests are routed to the edge that optimal for (usually, geographically close to) the viewer.  The edge caches are all independent.  If I request an object through CloudFront, and you request the same object, and our requests arrive at different edge locations, then neither of us will be served from cache.  If you are generating content on demand, you want to save your results to S3 so that you do not have to repeat the processing effort.
- CloudFront honors your `Cache-Control:` header (or overridden values in configuration) for expiration purposes, but does not guarantee to retain objects in cache until they expire.  Caches are volatile and CloudFront is no exception.  For this reason, too, your results need to be stored in S3 to avoid duplicate processing.

This is a much more complex solution than pre-processing.

I have a pool of millions of images, a large percentage of which would have a very low probability of being viewed, and this is an appropriate solution, here.  It was originally designed as a parallel solution to make up for deficiencies in a poorly-architected preprocessor that sometimes "forgot" to process everything correctly, but it worked so well that it is now the only service providing images.

However, if your motivation revolves around avoiding the storage cost of the preprocessed results, this solution won't entirely solve that.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. As you said at last eventually all the image sizes has to  be saved in the S3 BUCKET . If we are looking at reducing the storage cost then the EC2 server always need to process the image without pushing to S3